# How to create a relation between parameters of a function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a function which accepts 3 parameters: `data`, `changedProp` and `newPropValue`.

The `changedProp` should be bound to the `newPropValue` parameter and both have a relation to the data parameter.

Let's say we have the `Data` type:

```
interface Data {
  a: number,
  b: { x: number, y: number}
}
```

- When `changedProp` is `"a"` the `newPropValue` should be `number`.
- When `changedProp` is `"b"` the `newPropValue` should be `{ x: number, y: number }`.

Why in the example below the `newPropValue` in the if statement is not of type `{ x: number, y: number }`? How to achieve it?

```
interface Data {
  a: number,
  b: { x: number, y: number}
}

export function getChangedDataByProperty<T extends Data>(
  data: T,
  changedProp: keyof T,
  newPropValue: T[keyof T]
): T {
  if (changedProp === "b") {
    return {
      ...data,
      b: { // Error
        x: newPropValue.x, // why ts is not smart enough to detect that newPropValue is { x: number, y: number}?
        y: newPropValue.y,
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...data,
      x: newPropValue
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the TS [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5OALmRAFcBbAI2gBp9kqTtkAPE86u5ATw8ppQAvrhG4IrAA4B7KGGQwyIBGGDSQyAOYQwAYQAWcENoAm6TACEeABSjTJ0MDwA8AFWQTIIEwGc0GOAA+AAoGEwCSV3oCBENjCBNbexIAawgeaRhkKIYQCAB3JMkANTgAGzIISIBtNIys1wBdXABKSJwGYCzg2KNTIuQAXmHkACIqUZaOggIoHTIoDTwZmYA6dfDMaJXGZgYdtg4CotKKiFXWWmQAemvkfP0eZH0IPxBpeR8KODkPd7JNPpkGBpMgTDoICpgYZ5HlCnYSuVKshgH4WOxSAJuHxMVxhPsdji4SckeceNsViJKQwhB4yj4UMsZnMwAslgSCOtVps4BSZhjiQjTpUCVTkCIhEA).

Comment: Because `T[keyof T]` could be _any_ property. You could do e.g. https://tsplay.dev/mxaVZW to link the two _outside_ the function, but it still can't infer `newPropValue`'s type _inside_ the function without some help.

Comment: yes, any property of T which is "extends Data". So any property in Data.

At the place if  if (changedProp === "b") im narrowing it to the property "b".

But i assume TS is not able to make that deep connections.
When T extends Data...

what is actually keyof T? string or "a" | "b" ?

what is T[keyof T]?

Comment: `keyof T` is the union of the keys, `T[keyof T]` the union of the values.

Comment: so keyof T is "a" | "b" and T[keyof T] is number | { x: number, y: number }?
So hes just not smart to detect the relation?

Comment: typescript is smart enough to detect relation, but the relation is not specified in the parameters. You do not specify any link between changedProp and newPropValue

Comment: well maybe typescript is not that smartiim not able to find a solution event with another generic parameter for changedProp :-(

Comment: im happy with any solution. 
does somebody has an idea?

Comment: Would [this](https://tsplay.dev/m0bkqw) fit your requirements? If so, I would write up an answer explaining it.

Comment: This witchcraft looks good and i do understand it. Ur creating an object type with key: [key, value] entries and than u do [keyof Data] to get only the tuples. So its bassicly a list of [key, value] tuples. like a = ['a', number ] | ["b", { x: number, y: number }]. 
But what is this ...[changedProp, newPropvalue] i never seen something like this.
Can u pls post a link to that rest operator spread operator combination or describe it? it would also be amazing if you could provide ur solution as an answer to this post :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already discussed in the comments, there is currently no relation between `changedProp` and `newPropValue`. It's not some compiler limitation. You typed `changedProp` as `keyof T`, which is a union of all the keys, and `newPropValue` as `T[keyof T]` which is a union of all the value types.

To create a relation between both parameters, you could add a generic type which holds the type of `changedProp` and use it to derive the type of `newPropValue` as @jonrsharpe demonstrated. This would work for the caller of the function. But you would get assignability errors in the implementation. The compiler is currently only able to *discriminate* [discriminated unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions). But two types which depend on a generic type are *not* a *discriminated union*; control flow analysis will therefore not do any narrowing.

We need to build a *discriminated union* to make the compiler understand that checking the value of `changedProp` changes the type of `newPropValue`.

To keep the calling signature of the function as is, we make use of [*rest parameters*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#rest-parameters-and-arguments). This will allow us to use a *union of tuples* to describe possible combinations of parameters.

```
...[changedProp, newPropValue]: { 
    [K in keyof Data]: [changedProp: K, newPropValue: Data[K]] 
}[keyof Data]
```

As you correctly commented, the code above builds this union of tuples by mapping over the keys of `Data` and indexing the result with `keyof Data`. We also *destructure* the two tuple elements `changedProp` and `newPropValue` from the resulting tuple; a shortcut so we don't have to access the tuple to get the values later.

```
export function getChangedDataByProperty(
  data: Data,
  ...[changedProp, newPropValue]: { 
    [K in keyof Data]: [changedProp: K, newPropValue: Data[K]] 
  }[keyof Data]
) {
  if (changedProp === "b") {
    return {
      ...data,
      b: {
        x: newPropValue.x,
        y: newPropValue.y,
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...data,
      x: newPropValue
    }
  }
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUM5OALmRAFcBbAI2gBp9kqTtkAPE86u5ATw8ppQAvrhG4IrAA4B7KGGQwyIBGGDSQyAOYQwAYQAWcENoAm6TACEeABSjTJ0MDwAUDExmJoP9AgDp-ANoIhsYQJrb2tKQQAO4RkgBqcAA2ZBAAuszIDAQBANLIoMgA1hA80jBemJnIQSGm8SR5USCx8UmpECTmcPnp6dkEQgGl5ZU96bgAlDgMwJXOwUYNdpLIALybyABEVNszeAQEUDpkUBqHR37+7pg+V4zMOQ-s0XGrHWm+rPcPvBxtD4pL48X5HERXCHIITICDJADOKEux1O51mf38vlucDBBFerXe9k+EGeUJEYm0enqYR6Vnijhcl08AEYAEwAZnuTBwbBIbM5-2Q-Ohoiiu22URYrwADFE+MhpdCprhcJSDMsaR46asGc4mXyOVysq9+XKDeyRUIxXAJQrlaqdOrQmYtTYdXJGQwWYaGNypeazUKOZbrbb-QrA4qhFMgA)

Comment: Thank you very much :):
So the statement `...[changedProp, newPropValue]` is kind of ...rest, [changedProp, newPropValue] = rest ? I have never seen this kind of combination. Is it a trick in js?
if i would'nt need that type stuff i would just have the changeProp and newPropValue as normal params, right?

Comment: Do you know why my sollution with generics which is based on this post is not working?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75062903/why-typescript-behaves-differently-when-using-the-type-directly-vs-using-generic

Comment: @Znar - it is generally hard for the compiler to do any narrowing when generic types are involved. I could not really tell you *why* it fails. But from experience, you can't expect much control flow analysis with generic types.