# why typescript behaves differently when using the type directly vs using generics with extends?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I dont understand why the code behaves differently when using generics.
The topic is based on the answer for
[How to create a relation between parameters of a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75057096/how-to-create-a-relation-between-parameters-of-a-function/75059848#75059848)

```
interface Data {
  a: number,
  b: { x: number, y: number}
}

type GetKeyValueTuples<T> = { [Key in keyof T]: [Key, T[Key]] }[keyof T];

function getChangedDataByProperty<T extends Data>(
  ...[data, changedProp, newPropValue]: [T, ...GetKeyValueTuples<T>]
) {
  if (changedProp === "b") {
    changedProp
    return {
      ...data,
      b: {
        // why this has number, a, b types?
        x: newPropValue.x,
        y: newPropValue.y,
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...data,
      x: newPropValue
    }
  }
}

// why this behaves differently than the abvove function?
function getChangedDataByProperty2(
  ...[data, changedProp, newPropValue]: [Data, ...GetKeyValueTuples<Data>]
) {
  if (changedProp === "b") {
    changedProp
    return {
      ...data,
      b: {
        x: newPropValue.x,
        y: newPropValue.y,
      }
    }
  } else {
    return {
      ...data,
      x: newPropValue
    }
  }
}
```

[The ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#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-AFswtzdZs6FgWHw7XITWoqeY5Xs4X6suG3n8qcEPic5cbVfiyVAk0EE1yiAKpWj1WT7Ez2lT3Wl3dbY2y0RAA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getChangedDataByProperty2()` function's [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) is of a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions) type, and since TypeScript 4.6 we've been able to [destructure such discriminated unions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#cfa-destructured-discriminated-unions) into separate parameters to get the narrowing behavior you're seeing, where a check of the *discriminant* `changedProp` narrows the type of `newPropValue`.

On the other hand, `getChangedDataByProperty()`'s rest parameter is of a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type which is ultimately [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the same discriminated union type.   For whatever reason, TypeScript does not consider a generic type to be an acceptable discriminant for a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#discriminated-unions).  There is an issue filed at [microsoft/TypeScript#50652](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50652) about this, but it's currently marked as "needs investigation" so there's no official word on whether this is a bug, a design limitation, or can be interpreted as a feature request.  It's also on the backlog, which means that such official word might not be forthcoming.